# MySQL get percentage of year over year for each month

Tags: mysql, percentage, mom

I'm trying to get in the same result the last 12 months and their values vs same months from the last year and the percentage difference.

```
ThisYearMonth | ThisYearValue | LastYearMonth | LastYearDifAsPercent
--------------|---------------|---------------|---------------------
Dec 2015 -----|800 -----------|Dec 2014 ------|50 ------------------
Nov 2015 -----|350 -----------|Nov 2014 ------|-23 -----------------
```

Each select works OK, but when combined, i get

> [Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`month`, '%b %Y') AS ThisYearMonth,
    no_customer_growth as ThisYearCustGrowth,
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(`month`, INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'%b %Y') AS `LastYearMonth`,
    (
        SELECT
        ROUND((t1.no_customer_growth - t2.no_customer_growth) / t2.no_customer_growth * 100, 2)
        FROM cust_evolution AS t1
        INNER JOIN cust_evolution AS t2
        ON DATE_FORMAT(t1.`month`,'%b') = DATE_FORMAT(t2.`month`,'%b')
        AND DATE_FORMAT(t1.`month`,'%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(t2.`month`,'%Y') - 1
    ) AS `MoM % growth`
FROM cust_evolution
```

Thanks for your time and support!

Comment: As your error says, your subquery needs to return only one row. You might want to test your inner query to see what rows it return.